# C++ winapi pass mouse clicks on child windows to parent window

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I want to handle the clicks on child windows the same as clicks on parent window - how can I do that in winapi?

Currently, I can move the parent window by pressing anywhere on it but not on the child windows, because then it won't move. How can I change that?

Comment: Try SetCapture but I think you will have to move the window yourself in response to the captured mouse events.

Comment: Hard to make sense of this, you only "move" a child control by moving its parent.  Aim for the title bar, I guess.  Or just call MoveWindow().

Comment: You haven't thought this through. If you clicked into the client area of an edit control, for example, how would you propose to select text with a mouse, if the mouse move should instead move the parent window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer that works:

```
case WM_NCHITTEST: 
        if (hWnd==parent)
        return HTCAPTION;
        else return HTTRANSPARENT;
```

Answer (score 1):

Capture the mouse click on the desired child controls(s), and then send a `WM_SYSCOMMAND` message with `SC_DRAGMOVE` (0xF012, aka `SC_MOVE` OR'ed with 2) as the `wParam` parameter to the parent window. That will invoke a drag operation on the parent window.

This is a widely known trick, and well documented online (just not by Microsoft) if you do a search for `SC_DRAGMOVE`.